# Exit while loop when reaching last positional argument

Tags: bash, options

I want to adapt this so that when the function reaches the last positional argument, the while condition exits.

```
console_codes ()
{
 local exec=0
 local narg="$#" iarg=0
 while (( narg > 0 )); do
   opt="$1" ; iarg=$(( iarg + 1 ))
   case $opt in
    ("-V"|"--version")
      printf '%s\n' "Version"
      return 0
      ;;
    ("-h"|"--help")
      printf "Help.\n"
      return 0
      ;;
    ("-e"|"--exec") exec=1 ; shift 1 ;;
    (*) shift 1 ;;
   esac
 done
}
```

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: `shellcheck` only says `exec appears unused.`.  But the question is to make the loop exit after all positional arguments are exhausted or `--` is reached.

Answer (score 1):

You are using shift, so just check when "$1" is empty

```
while true; do
  [ -z "$1" ] && break
  echo "$1"
  shift
done
```

Comment: or just `while ! [ -z "$1" ]; do...`, or `while [ "$1" ]; do...` But note that that will also break the loop if one of the arguments is just the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You should read `man getopt getopts`, rather than re-re-re-inventing parsing options.

You could do your loop more compactly by realizing that `$#` is decremented by `shift`:

```
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]] ; do
  # some code using $1
 shift
done
```

Comment: This is a question about hacking, not about discouraging progressing this thing.